# NetworkCommsDotNet Two-way chat with one connection

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, chat, networkcomms.net

In the following project, messages are sent to the server only through the client.
I need every time the client sends a message to the server, the server program responds to the client using the Console.ReadLine () function, **without creating a new connection** and using the same connection that was already created;

For example, when the client says hello, wait or the server will say answer!

Of course, after searching, I realized that I should probably use connection.SendObject(), but I could not use it properly :(
(Of course, if this answer is correct!)

Thank you for your help

server :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NetworkCommsDotNet;
using NetworkCommsDotNet.Connections;
using System.Reflection;

namespace server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("Message", PrintIncomingMessage);
            Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 1000));

            Console.WriteLine("Server listening on:\n");
            foreach (System.Net.IPEndPoint localEndPoint in Connection.ExistingLocalListenEndPoints(ConnectionType.TCP))
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", localEndPoint.Address, localEndPoint.Port);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to close server.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the provided message to the console window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="header">The packet header associated with the incoming message</param>
        /// <param name="connection">The connection used by the incoming message</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message to be printed to the console</param>
        private static void PrintIncomingMessage(PacketHeader header, Connection connection, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);

        }

    }
}
```

client :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NetworkCommsDotNet;

namespace client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int loopCounter = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                string messageToSend = Console.ReadLine();
                NetworkComms.SendObject("Message", "192.168.1.1", 1000, messageToSend);
                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                    break;
                else loopCounter++;
            }
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to implement "Real-Time" (Always-Listening) Service , so thre are some better way : using SignalR Or Using Grpc have you tried those before ?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you saying "I'd like the server to respond with a message that is then also written out by the client?"

Comment: @AliBesharati ,thanks for your comment. It actually solved my problem. If you want put it on answer section that I accept it!

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to implement Real-time Application in .Net Such as:

1.`SignalR` (It uses WebSockets whenever possible)

2.`Grpc` (it uses http/2 and Streaming )

3.Also You can build An Application Using `MeesageBrokers` that implement `pub-sub` (publish-subscribe ) pattern like (`Redis` or `kafka` or ..)